# Prove random covariance matrix $\hat{\Sigma}_n$ converges to matrix $\Sigma$ almost surely.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ be an iid sequence of random $K$ vectors. Let $\mu = E(X)$ and $\Sigma = \operatorname{var}(X)$. Suppose $\Sigma$ is positive deﬁnite. Deﬁne the sequence of random $K \times K$ matrices$$\hat{\Sigma}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i =1}^n\ (X_i-\bar{X}_n)(X_i-\bar{X}_n)'$$Prove that $\hat{\Sigma}_n\to\Sigma$ almost surely.

I want to show the convergence taking advantage of the Frobenius norm.

That is
$$\big|\ \|\hat{\Sigma}_n\|_F\ -\|\Sigma\|_F\ \big|\to0\ \textrm{as}\ n\to\infty$$

But it turns out to be a heavy calculation containing information that I can't process by hand, is there a better way to tackle this?

Comment: if $\mathbb{P}(lim_{n\to \infty}\ X_n = X) = 1$, then we say $X_n \to X$ a.s

Answer (score 1):

I guess it suffices to show entry-wise convergence almost surely, i.e. $(\hat{\Sigma}_n)_{ij} \to \Sigma_{ij}$ almost surely for each $i,j$.

The $i,j$ entry of $\hat{\Sigma}_n$ can be rewritten as
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k)_i (X_k)_j
- \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k)_i\right)
\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n(X_k)_j\right).$$
By applying the law of large numbers on each term, we have almost sure convergence to
$$E[X_i X_j] - E[X_i] E[X_j] =: \Sigma_{ij}.$$

Comment: Thank you, I am confused by the step using LLN, which should give a conclusion that is convergence in probability rather than almost surely. Could you plz give more detail?

Comment: @ZKK The weak law of large numbers ensures convergence in probability, but under usual conditions this can be strengthened to the [strong law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) which ensures convergence almost surely.